# Looping through an empty array to fill out values on a table

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, nested-loops

I have a for loop with initialized empty array. On a table, I am supposed to list the i value, the j value, and the myList[i][j] value for each iteration. Sorry! I'm very new at Javascript and don't understand how the values are added to the array and what they are.

```
var myList=[ ];

for (var i=0; i<3; i++){

    myList[i]=[ ];

    for (var j=0; j<i; j++){

    myList[i][j]=10-(2*j);

    }

}
```

So for the first iteration: `i=0, j=0, myList[i][j]` is undefined. But how does it continue after this?

Answer (score 0):

var myList=[ ];

for (var i=0; i<3; i++){

```
myList[i]=[ ];

for (var j=0; j<i; j++){

myList[i][j].push();

}
```

}

Comment: myList[i][j] is not array this will return an error.

Answer (score 0):

when your code hit the second for for the first time `i` is zero so the condition for the second loop is false it never hits the inside of the for. But after the first time it s `j` is always less than `i` therefore it creates other elements. if you want to have at list one element you can try something like below.

```
for (var j=0; j<=i; j++){

    myList[i][j]=10-(2*j);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not allowing code to execute for i=0;j=0 in your second for loop and that's a reason for getting undefined at i=0;j=0 index in myList[i][j];

you are allowing your code to run for

```
[i] [j]
 1   0
 2   0
 2   1
```

indexes  only and aslo assigning values in above index positions only. and hence you are getting undefined at 
myList[0][0]